# Strange Printing in SymPy For Indexed Variables

Tags: sympy

I am trying to figure out how I can print an indexed variable in SymPy to make it look cleaner than below. I am not able to use Mathjax for some reason, so I apologize that there is just a photo to work with.

```py
import sympy
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
S = IndexedBase('S')
i,j,t = Idx('i'),Idx('j'),Idx('t')
S[i]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this image is a result of the code you posted? I tried it and it shows only `S_Idx(i)`, as I presume you expect

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn’t realize. Either way, the problem still persists with regards to how is printed in that it prints with Idx in the subscript.

Comment: apparently the answer is that there is no specific `latex` printer for `Idx` so the plain representation is used (all the latex printer does is basically provide a raw latex as an alternative semi-`repr` function). There should probably be added a separate case for `Idx` objects that uses their `label` instead of `repr`.

Comment: @Uriel could one implement an extension of the default printer to add this case? e.g. with https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#prettyprinter-class

Comment: @JuanPi I intended to provide such one yesterday but didn't get around posting my result. Posted an example now.

Answer (score 1):

As my previous comment states, it is currently not supported in the existing latex printer.

**However,** you can manually implement `_latex(self, expr)` for `Idx`, or **use a custom printer**:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter

class CustomLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_Idx(self, expr):
        return expr.name

    @classmethod
    def printer(cls, expr, **kwargs):
        return cls(kwargs).doprint(expr)

init_printing(use_latex='mathjax', latex_printer=CustomLatexPrinter.printer)
```

All I do here is simple **implement `_print_Idx` to return the label as a string** (through the `name` property) and **provide a printer function to match the signature `init_printing` requires** for a `latex_printer`.

Then, following your example

[image]